# Maya to Three.JS

Tags: three.js, maya

I have been attempting to learn three.js for a couple of weeks now. I was wondering if someone knew how I could proceed in answering my small issue I am having. Below you will find an exported maya .obj file that has been converted into a .js file

http://christopher-michaels.com/cart434/test/RD2/scenes/ (Only accessible through firefox)

The issue I am having is its not accepting my materials, nor is it accepting and lighting.

How do I go about adding these lighting and materials?

Comment: does your/the maya-exporter export an mtl-file with it? Check the material on the mesh that you add to the scene with console.log, what does it say? Does your lighting work for standard geometry like a cube? Also, the obj-file and mtl-file are text-based, so you can check manually what got exported, I would advise you trying to the problem with a cube exported from maya to begin with. Also maybe only use standard materials in Maya, not mental Ray or other stuff.

Comment: Hi Guygood thanks for the response, I am not sure what console.log is? Whatever i export I have no lighting, where it be a simple geometry or my tunnel. I do receive an .obj and .mtl file. I have used standard materials as well, but I still get the same consistent error.

Comment: well, you do something like "console.log(myOBJMesh)" where myOBJMesh is the variable that references the mesh object in your code. So you can check what material it uses and if the normals got exported and imported correctly. Also to exclude the obj file, have you tried loading your OBJ with the ThreeJS example, because there is already an example that imports objs that comes with the repository. If it works, than your other code is wrong, if not, your obj is wrong. ;)